# Delete copies of files in a folder

Tags: python

I have this folder.

[image: of]

Let's consider the files: **sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300_run-01_T1w.nii.gz** and **sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300_run-02_T1w.nii.gz**. They have the same initial part of the name, that is **sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300**.

I would like to code a script in Python that extract only one file among the ones with the same **sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300**, among the one with the same **sub-OAS30031_ses-d0427** and so on. It's not important which file is extracted, just one.

This because **sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300_run-01_T1w.nii.gz** and **sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300_run-02_T1w.nii.gz** are like copies and i don't want them.

Could you help me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `re` and `os` modules :

**PS : always have a copy of the original files if something goes wrong, it can be used again.**

```
import os,re
file = os.listdir()
match = []
for i in file:
    t = re.findall('_ses\-d(.*?)_',i)
    if t :
        if t[0] not in match :
            match.append(t[0])
        else :
            os.remove(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, also the number in OAS30027 can change in my folder. How should i edit you code ?

Comment: I get the error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
 'sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300_run-02_T1w.nii.gz'"

Comment: I tried the code in my system with files of the same names you provided, I am getting no error. Can you provide a traceback?

Comment: @Paolorossi, edited the code as per your first comment. Now it accomodates all the OAS.. values.

Comment: @Paolorossi Let me know after checking.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep it as simple as possible. I hope this helps:

```
import os

directory = 'directory_name' # put in the directory you want to search through
duplicate_file_lst = []

# loop through directory files
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
   if filename.startswith("sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300"):
       duplicate_file_lst.append(filename)

# Only keeps the first file in the list        
for file in duplicate_file_lst:
   if file != duplicate_file_lst[0]:
       os.remove(file)
```

Comment: I get the error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'sub-OAS30027_ses-d1300_run-02_T1w.nii.gz'"

Comment: And also, number in OAS30027 can change in my folder. How should i edit you code ?

Comment: I edited the code by not nesting the `for` loop, as well as fixing the `if` parameter in the second `for` loop. The “FileNotFoundError” is probably because it can’t loop through your directory. Are you sure you put the correct directory name for the variable `directory`?